# Redux nested duplicate properties are creating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-state-management

I am storing data in Redux store but instead of updating the store property its creating nested duplicates

[image]

**Index.js**

```
const initialStore = {
    user: {},
    brands: [],
    category: []
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={configureStore(initialStore)}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [
    thunk
];

const windowIfDefined = typeof window === 'undefined' ? null : window;
if (windowIfDefined && windowIfDefined.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
    enhancers.push(windowIfDefined.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
}

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
    );
}
```

**RootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import brandsReducer from './brandsReducer';
import userReducer from "./userReducer";
import categoryReducer from "./categoryReducer";
export default combineReducers({
    brands: brandsReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    category: categoryReducer
});
```

**CategoryReducer.js**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CATEGORIES':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { category: action.payload });
        case 'TOGGLE_CATEGORY_SELECTION':
            return {
                ...state, category: { ...state.category, category: action.payload }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I want to store in `store-> category -> Array` & `store-> brands -> Array` in this format.

Comment: Is the `category` state inside `CategoryReducer` an array? If so then shouldn't you be using `[]` instead of `{}` while destructuring and appending category?

Comment: Yes @MohammadAbdulAlim category is an array. Okay ll check

Answer (score 1):

in `CategoryReducer.js` have the case 'TOGGLE_CATEGORY_SELECTION' look like this

```
return { ...state, category: [ ...state.category, ...action.payload ] }
```

or if you do not want to add to values to category array in the store

```
return { ...state, category: action.payload }
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin TOGGLE_CATEGORY_SELECTION this action is not triggering only UPDATE_CATEGORIES is triggering.